# Minimal/Reference DAPLink Integration

Tags: stm32, swd

I'm in the process of developing a device driven by an STM32F030C8T6.

I want this to be programmable over USB (similar to ST-Link) to make development easier.

I'm led to believe that [ARM DAPLink](https://github.com/armmbed/DAPLink/) provides this sort of functionality.

My understanding of the process to integrate this is as follows:

1. Design my main circuit (including the ARM chip (U1) for that).
2. Add a secondary ARM chip (U2) to act as the DAPLink controller.
3. Connect two GPIO pins of U2 to the `SWD_CLK` and `SWD_IO` pins of U1.
4. Connect U2 to a USB interface
5. Flash DAPLink to U2 with a SWD Programmer
6. Flash application to U1 via USB and U2.

However, the documentation doesn't seem to be the best, and I can't find a reference implementation so, I'd apprreciate an answer that covers the following:

1. Is the above procedure roughly correct? If not, the premise of this whole question is wrong...
2. Is there a minimal reference implementation I can use for Step 2 above?
3. Is Step 5 above permanent, or would it need to be repeated each time I power-cycle the device? I'm not sure if ST32s have non-volatile storage on-board.

Comment: Why do you want to integrate a custom JTAG/SWD adapter onto custom PCB? Normally you would buy an ST-Link and use it to develop any amount of custom boards as long as the custom board has a standard JTAG/SWD connector. And that is necessary only if you want to debug over JTAG/SWD. These MCUs have bootloaders so if you only need to update firmware it can be done over UART.

Comment: @Justme - I just think it would be quite nice to be able to reprogram and debug my design without the need for a separate bit of hardware that I will inevitably lose. Plus, it's a bit of a learning exercise too.

Ideally, I could do with having full debugging but I didn't know you could program them over uart, I thought it had to be done over SWD

Comment: I don't see why it would make sense. For a small project with this small MCU, the debugging interface requires a bigger and more expensive MCU than the target, plus extra components, and space on PCB.

Comment: You can't see it being useful not needing a separate piece of hardware to program/debug a device?

Comment: No. Because like I said, you only need debugger for debugging. Firmware updates are possible without debugger. If you use a larger MCU with USB, you can directly use the USB for updating the firmware. An ST-Link is very cheap too, and you only need one.

Comment: Well debugging isn't exactly a non-trivial part of the development process... Also, whether or not you think it's worthwhile putting the effort in, I think it would be a cool thing to have on my project. I already have an STM dev board and I'm fairly sure I could snap the ST-Link off that and use it if I wanted to, so I'm not worried about expense, I just think this would be a cool thing to have

Comment: Well, for best debugging experience, why not use manufacturer provided debugger for that purpose? It only requires a connector, no other components, for SWD debugging. If you just want USB interface for serial comms console debugging, and firmware programming, an USB serial chip will do the job, if the MCU has no built-in USB interface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139280/discussion-between-scottishtapwater-and-justme).